# Why does absolute positioning effect getClientRects()

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, browser

I'm trying to get the total number of lines of text in a div and it was suggested to me that I could set the display property of the div to inline and the number of clientRects returned would be equal to the number of lines of text. However, I need to use absolute positioning on the div and when I do this it doesn't work.

Here's an example of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/cu5kb/

```
var x = document.createElement("div");
x.style.display = "inline";
x.style.whiteSpace = "pre-line";
x.style.position = "absolute";
var y = document.createTextNode("Text \n text");
x.appendChild(y);
```

Instead of 2 rects I get 1:

x.getClientRects().length === 1

Is there a way I can work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

There are [3 positioning schemes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme) in CSS 2.1

- Normal flow. In CSS 2.1, normal flow includes block formatting of block-level boxes, inline formatting of inline-level boxes, and relative positioning of block-level and inline-level boxes.
- Floats. In the float model, a box is first laid out according to the normal flow, then taken out of the flow and shifted to the left or right as far as possible. Content may flow along the side of a float.
- Absolute positioning. In the absolute positioning model, a box is removed from the normal flow entirely (it has no impact on later siblings) and assigned a position with respect to a containing block.

[Docs says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getClientRects), that `getClientRects` works only for inline elements and that's only in case of **normal flow**. Other schemes make it block or at least treat it as such and the [docs says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getClientRects)

> But for a block element, [browser] will return only a single rectangle.

Comment: I'm using white-space:pre-line so that my \n escape sequences are broken with <br>. Which results in 2 lines of text. Try applying absolute positioning to that div and see what happens. You'll get 1 instead of 2 lines.

Comment: Ah, yes I see now. So absolutely positioned elements are computed to be block level no matter what. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the class name of each div it does not matter where the divs are located in the DOM, the positioning has nothing to do with selecting the divs.

1. Set each div to have the same class name
2. Use `querySelectorAll` to retrieve the divs from the Dom

You can get your fiddle on here: http://jsfiddle.net/cu5kb/10/

```
    var textArrayTest = ["Text \n text", "Text \n text \nText \n text", "Text \n text\nText \n text \nText \n text"];


        for (var i = 0; i < textArrayTest.length; i++) {

            var x = document.createElement("div");
            x.style.position = "absolute";
            x.style.left = '0';
            x.style.top = (i * 100) + 'px';
            x.className += 'textDivs';

            x.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textArrayTest[i]));

            document.body.appendChild(x);
        };

 var getLines = function()
{
    var divHeight = this.offsetHeight;
    var lineHeight = parseInt(this.style.lineHeight);
    var lines = divHeight / lineHeight;
}
        setTimeout(function () {

            var processText = function () {

                var textDivs = document.body.querySelectorAll('.textDivs'),
                    msg = '';

                for (var i = 0; i < textDivs.length; i++) {

                    msg +='Number ' + (i + 1) + ' div has ' + getLines.call(textDivs[i]) + ' lines of text.\n\n';
                };

                alert(msg);
            }();

        }, 2000);
```

Comment: I don't want to count the '\n' to get the number of lines of text, that could have issues. What if the text has wrapped at some place due to the layout? Then you'll get the wrong amount of lines.